# Convert a list of Object values to a POJO

Tags: java, pojo

Hi I have the following return value from a dependency. I am trying to convert it to an POJO I represent it with.

Return type structure:

```
   DependencyAPIResult
     - List<Attribute>
```

Each Attribute has the following class definition:

```
public class Attribute {

    @NonNull private final AttributeKey key;
    @NonNull private final AttributeValue value;

    Getters
    .
    .
    .
    Setters
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to map this result to a POJO represented by:

```
public class MyPOJO {

    private pojoId;
    private pojoName;
    private pojoValue;
}
```

The way I am currently converting the result to a POJO is like this:

```
String pojoId = null;
String pojoName = null;
String pojoValue = null;

for (Attribute attribute : result.getAttributes()) {
    switch (attribute.getKey().getName()) {
    case "pojoId"
        id = attribute.getValue().getStringValue();
        break;
    case "pojoName":
        name = attribute.getValue().getStringValue();
        break;
    case "pojoValue":
        pojoValue = attribute.getValue().getStringValue();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there like an method/mapper or probably Java 8 lambda function which I can use to make this better? Thanks!

Comment: You can collect it to a Map (`result.getAttributes().stream().collect(toMap(a -> a.getKey().getName(), a -> a.getValue().getStringValue()))`) and then convert that to your POJO using a deserialization library like [Jackson](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store them in a `Map` instead of using a `for` with a `switch` :

```
Map<String, String> valuesByKeyName = 
result.getAttributes().stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getKey().getName(), 
                               v -> v.getValue().getStringValue()));

String id = valuesByKeyName.get("pojoId");
String name = valuesByKeyName.get("pojoName");
String pojoValue = valuesByKeyName.get("pojoValue");

Pojo pojo = new Pojo(id, name, pojoValue);
```